# Is 'or' used on the right-hand-side of an assignment pythonic?

Tags: python, coding-style, language-lawyer, boolean-logic, conditional-operator

### Situation

(Note: The following situation is just exemplary. This question applys to anything that can evaluate to bool)

A default list should be used if the user does not provide a custom list:

```
default_list = ...
custom_list = ...
if custom_list:
    list = custom_list
else:
    list = default_list
```

You can shorten this to:

```
default_list = ...
custom_list = ...
list = custom_list if custom_list else default_list
```

Now, as per https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/expressions.html#or ...

> The expression `x or y` first evaluates `x`; if *x* is *true*, its value is returned; otherwise, *y* is evaluated and the resulting value is returned.

..., `or` does not return a boolean, but rather the first value whose boolean conversion is not false. Therefore, the following would be valid code:

```
list = custom_list or default_list
```

This is similar to the C# Null Coalescing Operator, except it should be recoined in Python as *False Coalescing Operator*, which returns the first *non-false* argument.

### Question

The last example seems to be easier to read, but is it considered pythonic?

Neither *pep8* (the program) nor *pylint* do complain.

Comment: My opinion: Yes! But that's just an opinion. Can anyoone provide a PEP as 'hard evidence'?

Comment: Before we had conditional expressions, *that was the norm*. You used `or` to coalesce to a non-falsey default. Conditional expressions were only added to address some common problems with that approach.

Comment: http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0308/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is perfectly valid and you can use that. Even the [documentation of `or`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/expressions.html#or) has an example for the same.

> Note that neither and nor or restrict the value and type they return to `False` and `True`, but rather return the last evaluated argument. *This is sometimes useful, e.g., if `s` is a string that should be replaced by a default value if it is empty, the expression `s or 'foo'` yields the desired value.*

However, the `or` method has a limitation. If you want to purposefully allow a Non-Truthy value, then it is *not* possible with that.

Let us say you want to allow an empty list

```
my_list = [] or default_list
```

will always give `default_list`. For example,

```
print [] or [1, 2, 3]
# [1, 2, 3]
```

But with conditional expression we can handle it like this

```
custom_list if isinstance(custom_list, list) else default_list
```

Dusting off the older documents, quoting the [BDFL's FAQ](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/tags/r12beta4/Misc/FAQ),

> 4.16. Q. Is there an equivalent of C's "?:" ternary operator?
>
> A. Not directly.  In many cases you can mimic `a?b:c` with `a and b or
>   c`, but there's a flaw: if `b` is zero (or empty, or `None` -- anything
>   that tests false) then c will be selected instead.  In many cases you
>   can prove by looking at the code that this can't happen (e.g. because
>   b is a constant or has a type that can never be false), but in general
>   this can be a problem.
>
> Steve Majewski (or was it Tim Peters?) suggested the following
>   solution: `(a and [b] or [c])[0]`.  Because `[b]` is a singleton list it
>   is never false, so the wrong path is never taken; then applying `[0]` to
>   the whole thing gets the b or c that you really wanted.  Ugly, but it
>   gets you there in the rare cases where it is really inconvenient to
>   rewrite your code using 'if'.

Comment: True, even `print [1,2,3] or []` would print '[1,2,3]'. However, what I really wondered about was the pythonicity of the exercise.

Comment: @phresnel It is Pythonic. I included an example in the answer, which was given in the Python's documentation itself. Please check now.

Comment: I am still relatively new to python (since early 2013), and as a skeptic I would now like to ask: Is every example from the official documentation considered pythonic? (sorry for so much picking :P)

Comment: @phresnel Well, if we don't trust the official documentation, what else to trust? :-)

Comment: There was some language, I don't remember if it was C++, where official lawyers stated that the examples from the Standard are not necessarily examples of good code :(

Comment: Your problem example isn't that great. People would combine `or` and `and` to pick between two values the same way the conditional expression will pick between two alternatives. `foo = bar and spam or eggs` would now be written as `spam if bar else eggs`, because if `spam` is false-y then you'd end up with `eggs` anyway even if `bar` is truthy.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, using `or` for it's short-circuiting properties *was the norm*, before the conditional expression construct was added to the language.

It was, and still is, perfectly pythonic to use:

```
foo = bar or baz
```

to fall back to a default if `bar` is false-y (evaluates to false in a boolean context). The fact that it short-circuits also lets you do things like:

```
foo = bar or expensive_calculation(baz)  # only if bar is false-y
```

and not have `expensive_calculation()` execute if `bar` is truth-y (evaluates to true in a boolean context). Similarly, you can use `and` to ensure that preconditions are met:

```
foo = bar and bar(baz)  # call `bar()` only if it is truth-y
```

You *should* use a conditional expression for:

```
foo = bar and spam or eggs
```

however. That's what the conditional expression aims to replace. The idea was that if `bar` is truth-y, then `spam` is picked, else `eggs` is picked. But that breaks down if `spam` is false-y! This was a common source of errors, while

```
foo = spam if bar else eggs
```

always picks `spam` if `bar` is truth-y.